# Handle Windows Authentication in WebView - Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, .net, swift, uiwebview

I have a `.net` MVC Web App that I am logging in to through `windows authentication` in a `UIWebView`, and I wanted to know how I can handle errors(when the username/password isn't correct).  Currently here is what I have to login

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://webappaddress.com")
    urlComponents?.user = myUsername
    urlComponents?.password = myPassword

    let thisurl = urlComponents?.url
    let thisrequest = URLRequest(url: thisurl!)
    webView.loadRequest(thisrequest)
```

If the username and password are correct, then the web app shows in the `UIWebView`. If not, then the screen remains blank as the web app simply does not load without proper credentials.

Comment: Well I think in this case try using a hybrid way to implement the app. Like Sencha or PhoneGap based so you can even control the native and web related items properly. Also if your webapp in future need to access any phone devices components like GPS, Camera , Audio, microphone phone gap will have an added advantage,.

Comment: @VickyDhas Thanks for your comment. I ended up getting the web app to work and I can sign in properly, but I would definitely be interested in PhoneGap. One question I do have is whether or not PhoneGap would allow me to control the windows authentication in a better manner. Right now I can only login if i have the right credentials...in other words I can't actually check to see if the username/password is correct. The only way to know is if the webapp loads in the webview. Do you know a solution for either Swift or PhoneGap for handling authentication failures?

Comment: i think can . look for pgonegap website they  offer plugins

Answer (score 0):

An `UIWebView` can indeed load web page though HTTP request. Please check if you have exactly the same configuration as mind in your Info.plist
[image]